# link is not clickable at first time with ui-sref but after refresh of screen it does work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-sref

I have a hyperlink to be clickable and i have used ui-sref in the tag to navigate to certain page but it doesn't seem working for first time but rather works after refresh of page

My HTML

```
 <a class="col-sm-4 req-statements-count req-clickable" id="total-baselines" ng-model="vm.totalBaselines" ui-sref ="{{((vm.analysisOutputResult.baselinesfoundcount || 0) !==0) ? 'app.baselines-extractor':'.'}}">{{vm.analysisOutputResult.baselinesfoundcount || 0}} <span class="req-fr-nfr-label" id="fr-label">Total Baselines</span></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the logic and put directly the value of the route?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio yes,tried that way too

Comment: Have you looked if the class ".req-clickable" is invocated somewhere when making the click?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio yes it does,invocated how does this affect?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio tried removing that class..still didnt see any results:(

Comment: can you provide more code where your `vm.analysisOutputResult` is located, perhaps there is digest issue? (_Also I have no idea how you made_ `"."` _state working, seems like an invalid state name_)